# DROP PROCEDURE throws syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012

I have a `#temp` table where I have names of stored procedures.

```
DECLARE @object VARCHAR(200)
SET @object = (SELECT Top 1 Te.[this Object...] From #Temp Te)

IF OBJECT_ID(@object) IS NOT NULL
    DROP PROCEDURE @object
```

But on last step I get error

> Incorrect syntax near '@object'.

Is this because `@object` is of type `VARCHAR` or what ?

This is for SQL Server 2012

Comment: Use EXEC to run a SQL DROP statement that you have constructed inside a string - object identifiers/names cannot be variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can't do it like that. You need to use dynamic sql.
Something like :

```
DECLARE @object NVARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(max)
SET @object = (SELECT Top 1 Te.[this Object...] From #Temp Te)
IF OBJECT_ID(@object) IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
    SET @sql = 'DROP PROCEDURE ' + @object
    sp_executesql @sql
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look here:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/47186/how-can-i-drop-a-stored-procedure-whose-name-is-in-a-variable

You need to write an sql statement and execute it seperately.

Part from that answer:

```
declare @sql varchar(64);

set @sql = 'drop proc ' + @stored_procedure_name;

exec(@sql);
```

And you can replace @stored_procedure_name with @object

Answer (score 0):

DROP PROCEDURE needs an object not an varchar

try:

```
EXECUTE ('DROP PROCEDURE ' + @object)
```