# C# - Restore SQL Server database with Inline SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, restore

I am building a C# console application that restores a SQL Server database with pre defined parameters that can be modified in a switch menu. The focus of this application is simplicity. It's designed for anyone to be able to restore a SQL Server database at the press of a button. Yes, there should be someone who can perform this task competently, but there's a lot of ways things should be done... Regardless I've built the logic to loop through the backup directories and pick out the correct backup files based on a point in time. Everything works except the actual restore part.

From other questions I've read, I fear that it isn't possible to run SQL from C# that modifies the server in this way. I am reluctant to use SMO objects, because that involves extra complexities that I want to avoid, but if it is the only way I can do this, then that's what I'll do.

Whenever I try and run this code it complains that the `@dbName` value is invalid.

```
public static void RestoreDatabase(string Server_Name, string Instance_Name, string DB_Name, FileInfo BakFile, FileInfo DiffFile, FileInfo TrnFile, DateTime Point_In_Time)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Server_Name + "\\" + Instance_Name + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";

    string SqlQuery = @"ALTER DATABASE @dbName
                        SET SINGLE_USER
                        WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;

                        RESTORE DATABASE @dbName
                        FROM DISK = @BakFilePath

                        WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE;

                        RESTORE DATABASE @dbName
                        FROM DISK = @DiffFilePath
                        WITH NORECOVERY;

                        RESTORE DATABASE @dbName
                        FROM DISK = @TrnFilePath
                        WITH RECOVERY, STOPAT = @RecoveryTime;

                        ALTER DATABASE @dbName
                        SET MULTI_USER;";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = SqlQuery;

    try
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dbName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BakFilePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DiffFilePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TrnFilePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RecoveryTime", SqlDbType.DateTime));
        cmd.Parameters["@dbName"].Value = DB_Name;
        cmd.Parameters["@BakFilePath"].Value = BakFile.FullName;
        cmd.Parameters["@DiffFilePath"].Value = DiffFile.FullName;
        cmd.Parameters["@TrnFilePath"].Value = TrnFile.FullName;
        cmd.Parameters["@RecoveryTime"].Value = Point_In_Time;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Restoring {0}...", DB_Name);

        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Restore Complete!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection could not open. Error: {0}", ex);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }     
}
```

8/15/2016 10:38

Based on some of the answers, you guys are recommending dynamic SQL. I was worried about SQL injection, but only admins will have access to this program. Regardless I'll still add stricter validation because who doesn't love putting garbage input in for kicks.

I had attempted dynamic SQL. This was my code, however I did not spend much time checking for errors, so I'll go that route again and try and clean up any mistakes.

```
string SqlQuery = string.Format(@"DECLARE @dbName NVARCHAR(MAX), @strSQL NVarchar(MAX)=N'';
                            SET @dbName = {0};

                            SELECT
                            @strSQL += 'DECLARE @BakFilePath nvarchar(255) = N''{1}'','
                             + N' @DiffFilePath nvarchar(255) = N''{2}'','
                             + N' @TrnFilePath nvarchar(255) = N''{3}'','
                             + N' @RecoveryTime DateTime = N''{4}'''
                             + N' ALTER DATABASE '+ @dbName
                             + N' SET SINGLE_USER'
                             + N' WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;'
                             + N' RESTORE DATABASE ' + @dbName 
                             + N' FROM DISK = @BakFilePath'
                             + N' WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE;'
                             + N' RESTORE DATABASE ' + @dbName 
                             + N' FROM DISK = @DiffFilePath'
                             + N' WITH NORECOVERY;'  
                             + N' RESTORE DATABASE ' + @dbName 
                             + N' FROM DISK = @TrnFilePath'
                             + N' WITH RECOVERY, STOPAT = @RecoveryTime;'
                             + N' ALTER DATABASE ' + @dbName 
                             + N' SET MULTI_USER;
                             '
                             EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL",DB_Name, BakFile.FullName, DiffFile.FullName, TrnFile.FullName, Point_In_Time);
```

Comment: Could you show the entire output of it "complaining" about the dbName value?

Comment: Currently trying to figure out how to tee the output of my program to the screen and a file... very easy to do on Linux haha.

Comment: c# console program?  console.writeline()  and if you import system.windows.forms you can use messagebox.show(), system.file.io you can use File.WriteAllText(filepath).  you can also when running your program at command line use syntax such as c:\program.exe > results.txt to save it to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for everyone's answers, they lead me in the direction to choose dynamic SQL. The code below was the SQL solution that worked for me. I'll explain what's going on because holy cow does it get complicated (at least for me).
My C# application calls a function and I pass five parameters:

1. The database name
2. Full backup file path
3. Differential backup file path
4. Transactional backup file path
5. point in time to restore to

These values are then used in the SQL String's variable definitions. Once the variables are set in the SQL string, it then becomes regular dynamic SQL. Dynamic SQL is still a huge pain; figuring out all the single quotes caused me a lot of grief. Once the dynamic SQL is formatted correctly, it's just like any other SQL statement that is executed with C#.

UPDATE: Modified solution to include parameters for input values upon Scott Chamberlains request, and included the entire function as solution.

```
public static void RestoreDatabase(string Server_Name, string Instance_Name, string DB_Name,
                                   FileInfo BakFile, FileInfo DiffFile, FileInfo TrnFile, DateTime Point_In_Time)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
    conn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" + Server_Name + "\\" + Instance_Name + ";Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True";

    string SqlQuery = string.Format(@"DECLARE @strSQL NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
                                    SELECT
                                    @strSQL +=  N'ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName)
                                     + N' SET SINGLE_USER'
                                     + N' WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;'
                                     + N' RESTORE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) 
                                     + N' FROM DISK = N''' + @BakFilePath + ''''
                                     + N' WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE;'
                                     + N' RESTORE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName)  + 
                                     + N' FROM DISK = N''' + @DiffFilePath + ''''
                                     + N' WITH NORECOVERY;'  
                                     + N' RESTORE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName) 
                                     + N' FROM DISK = N''' + @TrnFilePath + ''''
                                     + N' WITH NORECOVERY, STOPAT =  N''' + @RecoveryTime + ''';'
                                     + N' RESTORE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName)
                                     + N' WITH RECOVERY;'
                                     + N' ALTER DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName)
                                     + N' SET MULTI_USER;
                                    ' 
                                     EXEC sp_executesql @strSQL");

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    cmd.CommandText = SqlQuery;
    try
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@dbName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 30));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BakFilePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@DiffFilePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@TrnFilePath", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 255));
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RecoveryTime", SqlDbType.NVarChar,30));
        cmd.Parameters["@dbName"].Value = DB_Name;
        cmd.Parameters["@BakFilePath"].Value = BakFile.FullName;
        cmd.Parameters["@DiffFilePath"].Value = DiffFile.FullName;
        cmd.Parameters["@TrnFilePath"].Value = TrnFile.FullName;
        cmd.Parameters["@RecoveryTime"].Value = Point_In_Time.ToString();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Restoring {0}...", DB_Name);
        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        Console.WriteLine("Restore Complete!");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Connection could not open. Error: {0}", ex);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

}
```

Comment: Your declares are super unsafe, get rid of them and go back to using `SqlParameter`s like you did in your original question. but then use them in combination with the code you have right now (everything after the `SELECT` is fine)

Answer (score 4):

unfortunately there is an issue with the way your SQL is written. I provided an answer to a question that had a similar underlying issue, you can find it here:

[DROP PROCEDURE throws syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38744149/drop-procedure-throws-syntax-error/38744191#38744191)

sql-server will complain about the usage of:

```
Restore Database @dbName
```

Because it is being passed as a literal string. You would need to write something like this to execute your code.

```
declare @sql varchar(64);

set @sql = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + @dbName;

exec(@sql);
```

**Update**
As per Scott's comment, using:

```
set @sql = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName);
```

Will escape the string to create a valid SQL Server delimited identifier:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx

Comment: Note, you may actually want to do `set @sql = 'RESTORE DATABASE ' + QUOTENAME(@dbName);` the [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) function will make sure the database name has proper `[ ]` around it so that if you get a database with a space in it's name it will restore correctly.

Comment: Thanks, I had not heard of / used that function before

Answer (score 1):

@dbName is invalid.

when passing a parameter you have to respect the rules of where variables are allowed to be used in sql syntax.  When using a SELECT statement you can use a variable in the column definition or where clause but it cannot be used to reference a specific database object.  The same holds true for ALTER DATABASE, ATLER TABLE, CREATE TABLE, etc.....

So basically the parameter cannot take place of the object name unless you then use dynamic sql such as building the sql string from the parameters as the other answer suggests.  Dynamic SQL in this manner can be very open to SQL Injection attacks so you should make sure your source(s) are trusted.

Lastly you ask if it is possible and the answer is yes it is very possible to run backup/alter database commands etc. from c# as long as you user has permissions and your sql statement is correct it will execute.

Answer (score 1):

You can't parameterize everything in SQL.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE customerID = @custID
```

is valid.

```
SELECT * FROM @tablename
```

is not. Neither is using ALTER DATABASE or RESTORE DATABASE with a parameter.

This is by design. The fix is to do the replacement in the string before you send it to SQL, but then of course you'll have to scrub the incoming parameters for bad things.

Comment: You don't have to scrub, SQL provides a function to escape the name so it replresents a proper object with [`QUOTENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx), so if you want to have a database named `This Is [a Weird] name; drop database foo;` it will be turned in to `[This Is [a Weird]] name; drop database foo;]` which [is a valid database name](http://i.stack.imgur.com/opZYS.png)